# How to increase the size of print output on console or export the outcome into excel?

Tags: r

I have performed a multiple comparison test in R and when I print the results, I can only see the results of 1000 rows. However, I need to see the whole outcome. My test is time dependent and I have 100 time points of 6 different measurements. You can find an example screenshot of the output from my console, which only shows the result from time point 45 to 100 but not the time points before.

```
Tukey<-emmeans(Data, list(pairwise ~ Types| Time), adjust = "tukey")
Tukey
```

[image]

I have already tried `options(max.print=100000)` but didn't change anything.

I am looking forward to your response.

EDIT: After request from Mr. Lahouir, I checked the print option if it run properly and seems to be.

```
getOption('max.print') 
[1] 100000
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
summ <- summary(Tukey[[2]])
```

You now have essentially a data frame, so just pull out a piece at a time.

```
summ[1:500, ]
summ[501:1000, ]
```

Etc.

Or save it with, say, `write.csv`

Comment: Dear @rvl Thank you very much for your support and suggestion. This definitely worked out! I dont want to bother you more but may I kindly ask if there is anyway to only show the results of p<0.05 ? I am already very happy with the result.

Comment: A growing community is saying “don’t go there” - there is nothing magical about p < .05. See https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-00874-8. But there is still a lot of pressure to ignore this advice. I’m confident your Excel skills are at least as good as mine.

Comment: Although I do agree about the p value comment, it is still functional and widely used for many scientific papers, at least for my field. However, I know that there is a huge debate if p should be out or not. Until that moment, I still have to use this approach:). But I do agree with your suggestion. Yes, I solved in excel but just wanted to be sure if there is any short cut. I am very grateful for your help and this really solved my problem. I wish nice day and Best Regards